# Skipping a Bad Record in Python Spark Pyspark Databricks Unknown Field Exception

Tags: python, apache-spark, error-handling, databricks, databricks-autoloader

I am wondering if someone might know how to skip a record that we are getting from a json file

Here is the error

[UNKNOWN_FIELD_EXCEPTION.NEW_FIELDS_IN_RECORD_WITH_FILE_PATH] Encountered unknown fields during parsing:
Here is the code that is failing

```
sent = spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles') \
  .option('cloudFiles.format', 'json') \
  .option('multiline', 'true') \
  .option('cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes', 'true') \
  .option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation', checkpoint_path) \
  .load(raw_files) \
  .withColumn('load_ts', F.current_timestamp()) \
  .writeStream \
  .format('delta') \
  .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_path) \
  .trigger(availableNow=True) \
  .option('mergeSchema', 'true') \
  .toTable(b_write_path)
```

Thanks!

I have not seen any documentation on how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what do you want to do with that data. By default, Databricks Autoloader uses the `addNewColumns` mode, which fails stream when encounters the new columns, but after restart it will handle them correctly.

You can use either `rescue` or `none` as schema evolution mode, like this.

```
.option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue")
```

In `rescue` mode, data for new columns will be put into a so-called "rescue column" which you can analyze if necessary, and the process won't fail.

In `none` mode, new columns are ignored and the process won't fail.

See [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/schema.html#how-does-auto-loader-schema-evolution-work) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!  I was banging my head against the wall